# No bluetooth and

Tags: kernel, drivers, bluetooth, asus

I know it's a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate... but I tried solutions that I found (about `sudo` `groupadd` `rfkill` and others) and it didn't work

So I will begin with that

```
$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on 
No default controller available
```

```
$ sudo systemctl stop bluetooth; sudo /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -n -d
bluetoothd[315732]: Bluetooth daemon 5.55
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DiscoverableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “AlwaysPairable” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “PairableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Privacy” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “JustWorksRepairing” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “TemporaryTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Name” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Class” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DeviceID” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “ReverseServiceDiscovery” in group “General”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Cache” in group “GATT”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “KeySize” in group “GATT”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “ExchangeMTU” in group “GATT”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Channels” in group “GATT”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRPageScanType” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRPageScanInterval” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRPageScanWindow” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRInquiryScanType” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRInquiryScanInterval” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRInquiryScanWindow” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRLinkSupervisionTimeout” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRPageTimeout” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRMinSniffInterval” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “BRMaxSniffInterval” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMinAdvertisementInterval” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMaxAdvertisementInterval” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMultiAdvertisementRotationInterval” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanIntervalAutoConnect” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanWindowAutoConnect” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanIntervalSuspend” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanWindowSuspend” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanIntervalDiscovery” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanWindowDiscovery” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanIntervalAdvMonitor” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanWindowAdvMonitor” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanIntervalConnect” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEScanWindowConnect” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMinConnectionInterval” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMaxConnectionInterval” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEConnectionLatency” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEConnectionSupervisionTimeout” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEAutoconnecttimeout” in group “Controller”
bluetoothd[315732]: src/adapter.c:adapter_init() sending read version command
bluetoothd[315732]: Starting SDP server
bluetoothd[315732]: src/sdpd-service.c:register_device_id() Adding device id record for 0002:1d6b:0246:0537
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Loading builtin plugins
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading hostname plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading wiimote plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading autopair plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading policy plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading a2dp plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading avrcp plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading network plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading input plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading hog plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading gap plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading scanparam plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading deviceinfo plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading midi plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:add_plugin() Loading battery plugin
bluetoothd[315732]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Loading plugins /usr/lib/bluetooth/plugins
bluetoothd[315732]: profiles/input/suspend-none.c:suspend_init() 
bluetoothd[315732]: profiles/network/manager.c:read_config() Config options: Security=true
bluetoothd[315732]: plugins/hostname.c:read_dmi_fallback() chassis: laptop
bluetoothd[315732]: plugins/hostname.c:read_dmi_fallback() major: 0x01 minor: 0x03
bluetoothd[315732]: src/main.c:main() Entering main loop
bluetoothd[315732]: src/rfkill.c:rfkill_event() RFKILL event idx 0 type 1 op 0 soft 0 hard 0
bluetoothd[315732]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
bluetoothd[315732]: src/adapter.c:read_version_complete() sending read supported commands command
bluetoothd[315732]: src/adapter.c:read_version_complete() sending read index list command
bluetoothd[315732]: src/rfkill.c:rfkill_event() RFKILL event idx 1 type 2 op 0 soft 0 hard 0
bluetoothd[315732]: src/rfkill.c:rfkill_event() RFKILL event idx 2 type 1 op 0 soft 0 hard 0
bluetoothd[315732]: src/adapter.c:read_commands_complete() Number of commands: 65
bluetoothd[315732]: src/adapter.c:read_commands_complete() Number of events: 35
bluetoothd[315732]: src/adapter.c:read_commands_complete() enabling kernel-side connection control
bluetoothd[315732]: src/adapter.c:read_index_list_complete() Number of controllers: 0
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.966
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Message Notification"
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.966
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Message Access"
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.966
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Phone Book Access"
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.966
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Synchronization"
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.966
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "File Transfer"
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.966
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Object Push"
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.966
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created ":1.966/org/bluez/obex/00005005_0000_1000_8000_0002ee000001/00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001"
bluetoothd[315732]: src/agent.c:add_default_agent() Default agent set to :1.5039 /agent
bluetoothd[315732]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x556a11044990: ref=1
bluetoothd[315732]: src/agent.c:register_agent() agent :1.5039
bluetoothd[315732]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x556a1106ea80: ref=1
bluetoothd[315732]: src/agent.c:register_agent() agent :1.962
bluetoothd[315732]: src/agent.c:add_default_agent() Default agent set to :1.962 /modules/bluedevil/Agent
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.973
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Headset Voice gateway"
bluetoothd[315732]: plugins/hostname.c:property_changed() static hostname: user-hostname
bluetoothd[315732]: plugins/hostname.c:property_changed() pretty hostname: 
bluetoothd[315732]: plugins/hostname.c:property_changed() chassis: laptop
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.973
bluetoothd[315732]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "Headset unit"
bluetoothd[315732]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x556a1106d970: ref=1
bluetoothd[315732]: src/agent.c:register_agent() agent :1.1001
bluetoothd[315732]: src/agent.c:add_default_agent() Default agent set to :1.1001 /org/bluez/agent/blueman
```

```
$ lsusb | grep -i bluetooth
$ lspci | grep -i bluetooth
$ lshw | grep -i bluetooth
bash: lshw: command not found
$ hwinfo | grep -i bluetooth
  E: RFKILL_NAME=asus-bluetooth
  E: RFKILL_TYPE=bluetooth
  bluetooth 692224 14 rfcomm,bnep,btusb,btrtl,btbcm,btintel, Live 0x0000000000000000
  ecdh_generic 16384 1 bluetooth, Live 0x0000000000000000
  rfkill 28672 11 bluetooth,asus_wmi,cfg80211, Live 0x0000000000000000
  crc16 16384 2 bluetooth,ext4, Live 0x0000000000000000
```

```
$ sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

```
$ lsmod | grep -i bluetooth
bluetooth             692224  14 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 28672  11 asus_wmi,bluetooth,cfg80211
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

then if you want me to try some commands or get some logs tell me so (I don't really know what to give more because everything seems fine (ig)) (bluetooth used to work on Windows; and on Linux before a kernel update some month ago)

Comment: bluetoothd is the middle level part. The low level is the kernel driver that is used to handle your specific bluetooth device. You'd  have to edit your question and add relevant informations about the bluetooth chipset, possible driver name and what you tested and searched about it.

Comment: I already talked about "what you tested and searched about it."; How to get "relevant informations about the bluetooth chipset, possible driver name"?

Comment: lsusb, lspci, lshw, hwinfo ... (install package if not installed, better run them as root / with sudo). search things relevant to bluetooth in their output

Comment: Sorry but grep isn't enough. You can't expect each line describint bluetooth to have the word bluetooth inside. Use | less and select the relevant parts

Comment: nothing more...

Comment: Nothing more to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cold boot or/and static discharge

Comment: excellent answer. I had to extra step and it was reinsert the usb bt dongle.